# Can two threads in the same process belong to different namespaces?

Tags: process, namespace, thread

The `task_struct` [structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L877) has an entry `nsproxy` which points to namespaces associated with the  `task_struct`.

My understanding is that `task_struct` can be used to represent both process and threads in the Linux kernel (please correct me if I'm wrong). If that's the case, are namespaces associated with each thread of a process s.t. different threads can be in different namespaces, or are all threads in a process in the same set of namespaces associated with the process ?

Comment: example in C (on a Go site): [One process in many namespaces!](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/goroutines-and-namespaces-part-1/#one-process-in-many-namespaces)

Comment: @A.B If a program puts different threads in different namespaces, then what do the entries in `/proc/$$/ns` correspond to .. namespace of the main thread of the process ? Because for each thread there would be an entry in `/proc/$$/task/ID/ns`

Comment: yes I guess so (the tgid).  You could run the example and study it in /proc. Also see man unshare and man setns: there are restrictions for mount namespace and user namespace for example.

Comment: @A.B that link leads somewhere else now